# Is there a law of Hachana?

Tags: talmud-gemara, maseches-eruvin, hachana-prep-for-weekday

The Gemara ([Eiruvin 38](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=3&daf=38&format=text)) says that R' Eliezer holds of Hachana or else one would be allowed to lechatchila make an eiruv on the second day.

On the other hand, when [R' Chisda](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=3&daf=38&format=text) says that there is such a thing as Hachana, Abaye and Raba bar Chanan are strong in their opinion that Hachana doesn't exist.

If there is no problem with Hachana, why doesn't R' Eliezer permit making an Eiruv lechatchila on Shabbos going into Yom Tov? (or is that Gemara arguing on Abaye and Rabba bar Chanan)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the last Tosfos on that page, that R. Eliezer does not hold of Hachanah and the reason one can not make an Eiruv Techumin is because one can not be Koneh Shevisah on Shabbos (and Yom Tov). On the other hand, he permits making an Eiruv Chatzeiros on Yom Tov.

Comment: What does he do with the Gemara which says that he does?

Comment: That gemoro in psochim does not agree with our gemoro